# How to convert docx to doc with terminal

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I looked around in google to see if there was a way to convert `docx` files to `doc` through the terminal and I found some potential solutions using perl's `xmllib`, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it, solely through the use of the terminal.

I guess a better question should've been, is there something similar to `textutil` for linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are packages like having such descriptions  , personally i never tested them. But do try.

[Unoconv -converter between LibreOffice document formats](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unoconv/) and for its [usage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/unoconv.1.html)

And [Office formats converter /jodconverter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jodconverter/) , also see its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/jodconverter.1.html)

**P.S. & TIP** : Try searching **Converter** in [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/) , you will get lots of results , try them and use as required.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if it works. (I'll mark it as answered once I confirm it)

Comment: Yes , please take your time , mark only **if** it works and provides required solution .